# Symfony2: How do i export the SonataAdminBundle listing data to excel sheet?

Tags: symfony, export-to-excel, symfony-sonata, export-to-pdf

I need to export sonata admin data via excel or pdf. How can i be able to achieve this? Is there any bundle that helps me do that?

Any ideas!?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know SonataAdminBundle has a built in support for json, xml, csv and xls export (works out of the box for me).

Comment: Could you please share link to the docs or tuts?

Comment: I don't think this feature is documented yet but it simply works when you configure sonata. Log into their demo website to see how it works (details on github page: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle).

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the admin **getExportFields()** method.

If the entity has some (X)-to-many or many-to-(X) relations you have to override all the fields

```
public function getExportFields()
{
     $exportFields = parent::getExportFields(); //It's not working in case of *-to many relation, so remove it, but it's ok for small customisation

     $exportFields["Date"] = 'date';             //if your date is an instance of DateTime, you have to format it
     $exportFields["User name"] = 'user.name';   // in case of *-to-many relations
     $exportFields["Status"] = 'statusAsString'; //for customise format implement getStatusAsString() in you entity
     return $exportFields;
}
```

To customise the type of report to download you have to override, removing the default one:

```
public function getExportFormats()
{
    return array(
        'json', 'xml', 'csv', 'xls'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented Bundle for Symfony and Sonata to export lists to PDF. You could get it here: https://github.com/whyte624/sonata-admin-extra-export-bundle. It is based on solution suggested here: http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/add-pdf-export-functionality-in-sonataadminbundle.html.
I know that the question is quite old, but hopefully it helps someone else.